# How to get session length in minute in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, connection-pooling, sql-session-state

Using following query in my procedure I can count to connection to my database

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(dbid) as 'Total Connections'
FROM 
    master.dbo.sysprocesses WITH (nolock)
WHERE 
    dbid = 7
```

This is working fine, is there any way to get length of the every connection/session in minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(n, login_time, GETDATE()) AS SessionTime
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses WITH (nolock)
WHERE dbid =7
```

You will get the time difference between `login_time` and now in minutes, which I reckon is session time.

BEWARE OF THIS:

> If the return value is out of range for int (-2,147,483,648 to
>   +2,147,483,647), an error is returned. **For millisecond, the maximum difference between startdate and enddate is 24 days, 20 hours, 31
>   minutes and 23.647 seconds. For second, the maximum difference is 68
>   years.**

From here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

NOTE: You should be okay as you are asking for minutes connected which is not likely to overflow any time soon!

Comment: Well, he's not going to have to worry about datediff limitations on minutes for SQL Server connections.

Comment: That's true enough ;-) But it may just be worth noting for somebody else who is after milliseconds or similar.